# How to display image on web page from ADODB.stream object

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic ASP question.
I need to show images on my webpage.
But because of the security reasons, I cannot simply put all of my images in the images folder in my website folder and I need to put them outside of my website folder.
For example, my website folder is located at:
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\
But I need to put images (which I want to show on my web pages) at:
C:\images\

I am trying to use ADODB.stream object to pull the images using ASP vb codes as shown below:

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "image/png"
Set adoStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
adoStream.Open
adoStream.Type = 1
FPath = "C:\images\1.png"
adoStream.LoadFromFile FPath

Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read 

adoStream.Close
Set adoStream = Nothing 
Response.End
%>
```

When I launch this webpage in internet explorer, the page shows a File Download window/message for downloading the image file "1.png" rather than displaying the image on the web page.
How can I fix the code to show the image on the web page rather than downloading the image file?

Answer (score 1):

That code generates an image as the return type, so there is no HTML to display the image in, if you call this code directly say it's called `image.asp` then you would do something like this in another page that displays HTML.

```html
<img src="image.asp" />
```

This will call your code and output the raw image binary as this is what `<img>` expects.

If you want to produce multiple images from the file system or database pass a querystring parameter such as `?id=yourimage` and change the code to select different images.