# what is the difference between response.write(image url) and response.binarywrite(image data)?

Tags: image, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on a VBscript asp page that is supposed to render a user's photo graph from our database, based on an ID value that is passed to the page via the URL string, to be used in various email functions.  This part works great, using the following code to render it:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
Response.BinaryWrite(rsAttPic("ind_photo_ext"))
```

I was asked to provide a default image, because if the user does not have an image on file in the DB, they get a broken image icon.  After some trial and error, I finally got something to work:

```
if (IsNull(rsAttPic("ind_photo_ext"))) then
  Response.Write("<img src='placeholderm.png'/>")
else
  Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
  Response.BinaryWrite(rsAttPic("ind_photo_ext"))
end if
```

This works when testing it through the presentation page on the website (showpic.asp) - both images display as expected, depending on the record being referenced in the URL.  However, when that page, showpic.asp, is referenced by other sources (emails sent via campaign software, confirmation emails generated by our CRM software), only the user image shows up as expected.  The generic image does not show in the emails, only a broken image link.

What is the difference between the two types of image presentation?  I did notice in testing that the user image appears in the browser in the center, black bground all the way around it, while the default image appears in the top left corner of the browser window, white bground.  Is that related?

Comment: One is a link to an image hosted on a website while the other is the actual binary representation of an image. It's a pretty big difference. The way I handle default placeholder images is to use `ADODB.Stream` object to load one from a file then read it into the `Response.BinaryWrite()` method. There is an example of how to do that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28822488/692942).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Lankymart. That helps.  After reading it, it occurred to us that we could do something similar on the server side, using a view to read the populated image or missing that, the default image, into a view that could then be called by the page.  Works like a charm.  Thanks again!

Comment: The other way you could have fixed the issue is to have provided the full path to the image, rather than a relative one.  e.g. `<img src='http://www.example.com/placeholderm.png'/>`